# Showing inequalities for $l^p$ sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

If I show that an inequality (e.g. Holder or Minkowski) holds for the $L^p$ space, then can I automatically conclude that the inequality also holds for $\ell^p$ sequences, just by integrating wrt. the counting measure?
Thanks!

Comment: If you didn't use any specific properties of the measure, then yes, since the sequence spaces are, as you note, also $L^p$ spaces. If you use specific properties of the measure, you need to check whether the counting measure has these properties.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 1):

If you didn't use any specific properties of the measure, then yes, since the sequence spaces are, as you note, also $L^p$ spaces. If you use specific properties of the measure, you need to check whether the counting measure has these properties. –  [Daniel Fischer](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83702/daniel-fischer)